# Java email client application android : "javax.mail.MessagingException: Host is unresolved: imap.gmail.com "

Tags: java, android, email

I'm creating an email client application.
During the login I'm trying to pass a string with the IMAPHOST (example imap.gmail.com) but whenever I attempt server answers me, return this error:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Host is unresolved: imap.gmail.com ;
```

Someone can help me? This is a part of code:

```
  public class Mail extends javax.mail.Authenticator implements Parcelable {
    private String user;
    private String pass;

    private String port;
    private String sport;

    private String smtpHost;
    private String imapHost;

    private boolean auth;

    private boolean debuggable;

    private Multipart multipart;


    private String _ID;

    public Mail() {

        smtpHost = "";
        imapHost = "";

        port = "465"; // default smtp port
        sport = "465"; // default socketfactory port

        user = ""; // username
        pass = ""; // password

        ID = "";

        debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off
        auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on

       multipart = new MimeMultipart();


    public Mail(String smtpHost,String imapHost,String user, String pass) {
        this();
        smtpHost = smtpHost;
        imapHost = imapHost;
        user = user;
        pass = pass;
    }

    @Override
    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass);
    }

    private Properties _setProperties() {
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.put("mail.trasport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", smtpHost);

        props.put("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
        props.put("mail.imaps.host", imapHost);

        if (_debuggable) {
            props.put("mail.debug", "true");
        }
        if (_auth) {
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        }

        props.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", sport);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

        return props;
    }


    public boolean loginIsValid(){

        Store store = null;

        try {
            store = this.getStore();
            store.connect();

            // No Exception thrown, Successful login.
            // Close service connection until actual use
            store.close();

        } catch (AuthenticationFailedException e) {
            return false;

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            //TODO Handle correctly
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }

        return true;
    }


    private Store getStore() throws NoSuchProviderException {
        Properties props = this._setProperties();

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this);
        return session.getStore("imaps");
    }

  }
```

Comment: btw: your argument constructor code makes very little sense

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error in my application. I see that the error is caused because the store connection was not closed when i previously ran the application.

**Solution you should try**

Please kill the application in task manager of your mobile and run again. I also suggest you to call store.close() method.